# Finding the radius of excircles from a right angled triangle

Tags: circles, triangles, pythagorean-triples

Right-angled triangles have $3$ excircles. I'm struggling to find a formula which gives me the radius of all three excircles. I've been struggling with this for a while. I've done some Googling, and I think I have parts of the correct formula:

\begin{align}
s &= \frac{a+b+c}{2}
&
A &= \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}  \\[0.5em]
r_1 &= \frac{A}{s-a}
&
r_2 &= \frac{A}{s-b}
\hspace{3em}
r_3 = \frac{A}{s-c}
\end{align}

$A$ is the area of the right-angled triangle;
$a$, $b$, and $c$ are sides of the right-angled triangle; $s$ is the semi-perimeter of the right-angled triangle; $r_1, r_2$ and $r_3$ are the radius of the excircles.

Can anyone find the formula? (Preferably I would like a formula without using any angles.)

Comment: You can express the ex-radii in terms of inradius but that's the simplest you can get, for e.g., $r_1=r\frac{s}{s-a}$ Edit: oh it's a right angle triangle didn't notice.

Comment: Would $r_1=\frac{ab}{2(s-a)}$ , $r_2=\frac{ab}{2(s-b)}$ work? Where i assumed c is hypotenuse.

Comment: @Mann Perfect!!!! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem:), and this is how you can arrive at the result!

We know that $\Delta = \frac{abc}{4R}$

Now I will assume that $c$ is the hypotenuse. Draw a circum-circle around your triangle you can easily observe by Thales theorem that $c$ is the diameter of the circle . Hence $c=2R$, Therefore $\Delta = \frac{ab}{2}$ 
 or Area is triangle = $\frac{1}{2}$ * base * height.